# Using z-index on number of div s and their respective hovers while retaining the original layering when not hovered

Tags: html, hover, z-index, opacity, overlap

**Background check:**
 1. Just recently got into basic html and css.
 2. Javascripts not allowed.
 3. Did search the website, didn't find matching topic (or couldn't understand it).
 4. Vague knowledge of z-index and hover.
 5. Offline page. Using Google Chrome to view page. Editing using Notepad.

**What I want:** 
I need to stack 5 images over one another in horizontal sequence. For example, in this code I wanted 5 country flags (all links,equal sized,distinguished using "left: px;") to be overlapping each other in a sequence with 0.99999 link opacity and 1.0 opacity when hovered upon. When not hovered upon, the images should go back to the way they were INSTEAD of changing the original indexing.

*Would prefer modifications of this code over completely different alternatives due to knowledge limitations.*

**What I did:**
Used div for each image and created css for each div and their respective hovers [after creating css for each img failed (retaining of z-index problem)]. Now after doing this, the hovering isn't working either.

***Problem:*** 1. Hovering/Opacity not working. 2. z-index does not retain after hovering.

P.S. Apologies for amateur work here and the question.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  Europe: A never ending journey
 </title>
<style type="text/css">
div.mainRunner
  {
  position: absolute;
  }
div.transbox1
  {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   opacity:0.99999;

  }
div.transbox1:hover
  {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity:1.0;
  }

div.transbox2
  {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   top: 0px;
   left: 80px;
   opacity:0.99999;

  }
div.transbox2:hover
  {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   top: 0px;
   left: 80px;
   opacity:1.0;
  }
div.transbox3
  {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 3;
   top: 0px;
   left: 160px;
   opacity:0.99999;

  }
div.transbox3:hover
  {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 3;
   top: 0px;
   left: 160px;
   opacity:1.0;
  }
div.transbox4
  {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 4;
   top: 0px;
   left: 240px;
   opacity:0.99999;

  }
div.transbox4:hover
  {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 4;
   top: 0px;
   left: 240px;
   opacity:1.0;
  }
div.transbox5
  {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 5;
   top: 0px;
   left: 320px;
   opacity:0.99999;

  }
div.transbox5:hover
  {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 5;
   top: 0px;
   left: 320px;
   opacity:1.0;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0px" topmargin="0px" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px">
 <div class="mainRunner">
  <div class="transbox1">
   <a href="Italy.html"><img src="Italy.jpg" width="800" height="450"></a>
  </div>
 <div class="transbox2">
   <a href="France.html"><img src="France.jpg" width="800" height="450"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="transbox3">
  <a href="Germany.html"><img src="Germany.jpg" width="800" height="450"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="transbox4">
  <a href="Switzerland.html"><img src="Switzerland.jpg" width="800" height="450"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="transbox5">
  <a href="UnitedKingdom.html"><img src="United Kingdom.jpg" width="800" height="450"></a>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try setting z-index to 10 for all the :hover stylings.

Comment: Oh God! Thanks a lot! Been experimenting this for hours. Working now! Need to practice more on this.

Comment: So as not to confuse, I only picked 10 because it is greater than all the other layers z-index. Your problem was that you were setting the z-index to be the same level when in both normal state (unhovered) and in the hover state. It needed to be greater than the z-index of any elements you wish it to show in front of. P.S. an upvote on my comment would be nice ;)

Comment: Yeah. :O I figured that out after more experimenting! Thanks for the help. Didn't take it for granted :D Hence, the experimenting. And I just Registered here. When I gain the reputation to be allowed to upvote, I will. I did click Accept Answer. :) Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting it as an answer because it is the answer (and I am trying to accumulate some rep =):

Set z-index for elements in :hover state to be greater than z-index of the elements you wish for it to be shown in front of.

Comment: :D Accepted. I'm a noob. Will voteup when I get the reputation to be allowed to do so!